# How to run repair twice a week using reaper

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I need to schedule repair to run on the existing Cassandra twice a week, once I added the first schedule I can't add the second schedule due to the following error, is there any way to run the repair twice a week in reaper?

[image]

Comment: What is your first schedule?

Comment: Every week on Sunday at 6 pm

Comment: You should just change it to run after every 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create multiple schedules for a table because running multiple repair sessions on the same table is not recommended.

If you want to setup different schedules for different keyspaces/tables, you need to explicitly specify the keyspace and/or table when setting up the schedule.

As a side note, the recommended repair interval is once every `gc_grace_seconds`. The default GCGS is 10 days (`864000`) so running repairs once a week is sufficient. Cheers!